# Help find Manhwa about a girl reincarnated who wants to get along with her step-kids

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The girl marries an older man, who trains her to take over his estate because he is dying. She is not the children's biological mother, but the man leaves her with four children, who—through many misunderstandings—end up hating her. On the wedding day of the oldest boy, who stands to inherit the title, she leaves and is killed on her way. She is then reincarnated back to the day of her husband's death. She now wants to see if she can understand and get to know the children better.

Answer (score 7):

This is *[The Fantasie of a Stepmother](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-fantasie-of-a-stepmother)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-fantasie-of-a-stepmother/info).

> They called her the Iron Widow. **When her husband died, he left her to manage not only his vast holdings but also his four children**. Young and inexperienced, Shuri nonetheless tried her best to raise them, despite **their bitter attitude towards her**. She is finally free to live her own life as her eldest son marries... only to find herself mysteriously reset to seven years ago—the night of her husband's funeral. Can Shuri find happiness with this second chance at a new destiny?

[image: Cover]

Synopsis covers much of the question, although strangely leaves out that she goes back in time because she died.

[image: The four children]

The four children are above; all of them dislike her in the original timeline. The story starts with the eldest getting married, and being told by the bride that she shouldn't attend her adopted son's wedding, at his request. She decides to leave, but is ambushed on the way by bandits. She finds herself back in time, on the day of her husband's funeral, seven years in the past.